# The root certificate of the certificate chain is self-signed, and untrusted

Tags: c++, apache, qt, ubuntu

I purchased a certificate on Godaddy. 
From them, I got three files: certificate.crt, certificatechain.crt, private.key

I have a QT app communicating with SSL to a Ubuntu server running Flask.

The website is working and running on https.

I don't have any problem on the Apache side,but here how I use the certificates.

In /etc/apache2/site-enabled/MyFlaskApp.conf

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certificatechain.crt
```

In QT:

```
void InitSSL()
{
    m_sslConfiguration.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);

    // Set certificate to configuration
    QFile certFile;
    certFile.setFileName(path_certificate);
    if(certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QList<QSslCertificate> certificates;
        QSslCertificate certificate(&certFile, QSsl::Der);
        certificates.append(certificate);
        m_sslConfiguration.setCaCertificates(certificates);
    }

    QFile certChain;
    certChain.setFileName(path_certificate_chain);
    if(certChain.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QList<QSslCertificate> certificates;
        QSslCertificate certificate(&certChain, QSsl::Der);
        certificates.append(certificate);
        m_sslConfiguration.setLocalCertificateChain(certificates);
    }

    QFile keyFile;
    keyFile.setFileName(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_KEY_PATH_SSL);
    if(keyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QSslKey key= QSslKey(keyFile.readAll(), QSsl::Rsa);
        m_sslConfiguration.setPrivateKey(key);
    }
}
```

I always get an SSL error saying, the root certificate of the certificate chain is self-signed, and untrusted".

It is not self signed, I purchased the certificate on GoDaddy.

Also, let me know what differences it makes if the QT app runs on Windows or Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are mixing the certificate file and the chain file in your code. You are setting the local certificate as a CA certificates chain and the CA certificates chain file as a full certificate chain. You also need to load all CA certificates from the chain file. I'm assuming that `certificate.crt` contains only the local certificate file and `certificatechain.crt` contains only the intermediate certificates and not the local certificate.

On the other hand, what are you trying to achieve? Have you enabled both client side and server side authentication because you are setting the local certificate and key on the client side? In that case you obviously should have two sets of certificates.

Anyway, you could try the following code to configure your Qt application. Qt is a cross-platform environment so there shouldn't be differences if you have configured the same `openssl` version on both platforms.

```
void InitSSL()
{
    m_sslConfiguration.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);

    // Set certificate to configuration
    QFile certificate_file(path_certificate);
    if (!certificate_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qWarning() << "error opening certificate file"
                   << QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(certificate_file.fileName());
        return;
    }

    QSslCertificate certificate(&certificate_file, QSsl::Der);
    certificate_file.close();
    if (!certificate.isValid())
    {
        qWarning() << "Certificate " << rCertificateFileName << " is not valid:"
                    << "valid from " << certificate.effectiveDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    << " to " << certificate.expiryDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return;
    }
    m_sslConfiguration.setLocalCertificate(certificate);

    // Set CA chain to configuration
    QList<QSslCertificate> ca_certificates = QSslCertificate::fromPath(path_certificate_chain, QSsl::Der);
    if (ca_certificates.isEmpty())
    {
        qWarning() << "error loading CA certificates from file " << path_certificate_chain;
        return;
    }
    m_sslConfiguration.setCaCertificates(ca_certificates);

    // Set key to configuration
    QString key_file_path(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_KEY_PATH_SSL);
    QFile key_file(key_file_path);
    if (!key_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qWarning() << "Error opening key file "
                   << QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(key_file.fileName());
        return;
    }
    QSslKey key(&key_file, QSsl::Rsa);
    key_file.close();
    if (key.isNull())
    {
        qWarning() << "Key " << key_file_path << " is null";
        return;
    }
    m_sslConfiguration.setPrivateKey(key);
}
```

Instead of [QSslCertificate::fromPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslcertificate.html#fromPath) you can load CA certificates from the file also with [QSslCertificate::fromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslcertificate.html#fromData) or [QSslCertificate::fromDevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslcertificate.html#fromDevice).

Are you sure the certificate files are in DER format? In case they are PEM you can remove `QSsl::Der` because `QSsl::Pem` is the default.

Comment: You nailed it asking "what are you trying to achieve?". I'm a little bit confused. I have the .crt and .key set on Apache server. My website is running on https://. What do I need in the client(QT) to verify that the .crt received is trusted? When I only use "m_sslConf.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);", I'm transfering file correctly through SSL to the server, but is it secure? I don't get it how to set up properly my SSL connection in QT so it validates the .crt received.

Comment: @vincedjango "What do I need in the client(QT) to verify that the .crt received is trusted?" Nothing. Qt uses OpenSSL and that comes with its own set of trusted certificates. It should work straight out of the box if your server is set up correctly: Qt should reject connections to servers with untrusted certificates. The chain of trust from a CA root is established by the certificate chain that the server sends out along with the server certificate. Ensure that things work correctly when you connect to the server via a web browser.